# Is there a meaning in a name marked on the rear of a headstone rather than the front?

Tags: death-records, grave-marker

I have found a family headstone with the names of the deceased on the front (with many details), and a military cross (for their son) in front of the stone. On the rear of the stone is a name and age, but no years. If the person on the rear is who I believe it to be, they would have pre-deceased their parents (who are on the front of the stone) by many years. I wonder if there is some significance to carving a name in the rear rather than the front?

Comment: Guessing (so not answering): The name is on the rear because they ran out of space on the front. (You may know if that makes sense) Re dying before their parents - bear in mind that names might not be carved in sequence and that the stone may have been erected after a later death and not after the first burial. It's also possible that an out of sequence name might represent someone buried elsewhere so added as an afterthought.

Comment: Interesting idea.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Please take a moment to view the [tour] and look over the [help] to see more about how the site works.

Comment: Perhaps the current back of the stone was originally the front? We considered doing that when we added my dad's uncle (died 1980) to the back of an old family gravestone. (In the end, we kept the old matching fronts outward.)